# Automated E-Mail styling

Tags: html, css, email

Im trying to create automated emails when a user registers on my website. It is important that the emails look fairly nice.

I have designed an email template in HTML, heres how it looks:
[image]

However, when the email is viewed in Outlook after being sent through the server, it looks like this:
[image]

Which is obviously not quite right. I understand that different email clients will all handle HTML and CSS differently, but what is the right way of doing this so that it works in as many different clients as possible?

This is my current code that is sent through the PHP Mail function:

```
<html>
<style>
    </style>
<body style='background-color: #b5b5b5; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <center>
    <div style='max-width: 600px; background-color: #5a5a5a; padding: 20px; margin-top: 30px;'>
        <img style='height: 30px; margin: 20px;' src='http://favourite.es/icon/system/branding.png'>
    </div>
    <div style='max-width: 600px;
        background-color: #e8e8e8; padding: 20px; color: #222222; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;'>
        <p style='font-size: 20px;'>Welcome to Favourite.es!</p>
        <p>Hi $newFirstname, welcome to Favourite.es,<br>your new personalised homepage for modern browsers.</p>
        <p>Thank you for registering.<br>Your account PIN is: $pin</p>
        <p>Remember to keep your PIN a secret, anyone who has your PIN can view and edit your Tiles.</p>
        <center>
        <br>
        <p style='font-size: 13px; color: #727070;'>If you have any questions, contact us at hello@favourite.es<br>You are receiving this email because you registered at favourite.es</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style='max-width: 600px;
        background-color: #5a5a5a;
        padding: 20px;'>
        <img style='height: 15px;
        display: inline-block;' src='http://favourite.es/icon/system/splycdsquare.png'>
        <img style='height: 15px;
        display: inline-block;' src='http://favourite.es/icon/system/branding.png'>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

I decided to keep the CSS inline as I thought this would be the easiest for a mail client to utilise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having something to test on, I can only give a few insights.

You most likely need to remove the inline padding on the individual divs. If necessary replace with 'padding: 0 20px;' or 'padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;'

I have coded for email extensively and can tell you divs are not easy to work with. Inline styling is almost always correct. Look into using an inline tool like [Zurb Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) or read about how to set up your HTML emails in 'old-school' table format. This is always the safest bet.

Comment: Thanks! Using Zurb Ink really helped :)